# navigation when including content pages in different templates

Tags: jsf, navigation

A login facelet (login.xhtml) is loaded in two different contexts:

- login-page.xhtml (from a link "Log In" in the navigation bar)
- adverts.xhtml (when clicking on a "Contact Advertiser" link in one advert)

When the login is successful, the navigation differs:

- when login.xhtml is included in the login-page template, it should navigate to home.xhtml
- when login.xhtml is included in the adverts.xhtml overlay, it should remain in adverts.xhtml.

The login.xhtml has a Login button which invokes the login() function in Session.java.

- writing navigation logic in Session.java is discarded.
- the login.xhtml is reused in different contexts, looking into navigation cases in jsf-config.xml.
- version is Java EE 7 / JSF 2.2.

I would like to know a good design to implement this requirement.

Code is not necessary.

Comment: The login.xhtml has a Login button which invokes the login() function in Session.java. The idea of writing navigation logic in Session.java is discarded. Since the login.xhtml is reused in different contexts, I suppose that we need a navigation rule in jsf-config.xml. The version is JavaEE 7 / JSF 2.2.

Comment: Thanks and you can then remove the comment... Keeps the comments clean

Comment: _'writing navigation logic in Session.java is discarded.'_  Why? If you need to return to the current page except when it is on the login-page (that is how I understand your requirement) then that is not much navigation logic and you keep everything together (instead of returning a string that needs to be interpreted in a faces-config file. But using a faces-config file is an option too. Both are 'valid' and not bad design at all

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will use the faces-config finally. In order to keep the login action generic and reusable, not limited to these two pages, I prefer that the login method in java will return "ok" or "fail", and define the next view in the config file.

Comment: It is generic too when you do it in java. You just return null or an empty string and it returns to the same page you were on. You return the home.xhtml in other cases. Just 'detect' via FacesContext which page you are on.

Comment: But that's the problem, if you want to use tomorrow the login function in another context you will have to write navigation logic in the java, so it is not generic. I definitely want to keep login method ignorant of where it is invoked. I appreciate your input.

Comment: What do you mean by different contex then? A different app? Then you could make it configurable in your applicationconfig like all existing login frameworks do e.g. picketlink  Then it is even jsf independent. Or you could make a convention and then it is generic again.

Comment: Thanks. No, I meant a different view, a different use case.

Comment: Then you can do it in the java class without any need for changes.